# problems with Hmisc-labelled objects in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I get the message

> Error:no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of
>   class "labelled"

when I try to plot my graphs using `ggplot2` and R. I have labelled my variables in my data frame using `Hmisc::label` and I think this is the problem. How do I solve this issue?

My labels look like this:

```
   label(data$results_lp)="Lumbure Puncture Results"
   label(data$hiv_test)="HIV Test done"
   label(data$outcome)="Outcome at Discharge"
   label(data$vac_10mnth_complete)="Vaccinne 10months complete"
   label(data$vac_3mnth_complete)="Vaccine 3months complete"
   label(data$vac_uptodate)="Vaccine up to date"
   label(data$dx1_pneum_rcd)="Pneumonia Recorded"
   label(data$mal)="Malaria"
   label(data$dx1_malaria)="Documented Malaria"
   label(data$dehydrat)="Dehydration"
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: The structure of Hmisc predates ggplot2 by almost a decade, and it was geared towards standard and lattice graphics. Using it with ggplot will always lead you into trouble, so I suggest that you either stay withing the Hmisc framework, or use some alterative to label, such as directlabel.

Comment: I use `Hmisc` `label`s routinely with `ggplot2` and very seldom run into a problem.  BTW the code above should instead use the much more concise `Hmisc::upData` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the labels for plotting:

```
library(Hmisc)

DF <- data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:2,5)),y=1:10)

label(DF$x)="xLab"
label(DF$y)="yLab"

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot()
#Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type labelled. Defaulting to continuous

ggplot(DF,aes(x=factor(unclass(x)),y=unclass(y))) + geom_boxplot()
#no warning
```

Unfortunately you don't give the details necessary to reproduce your error and give a customized solution.

Comment: labels very seldom clash with `ggplot2`.  Here are ways to make use of labels with ggplot2, and to typeset units of measurements correctly on axes: https://hbiostat.org/rflow/graphics.html#sec-graphics-ggplot2