# How to group column names as in this data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which was ready-made for me, and apparently some columns are grouped together by some underlying mechanism. How can I group column names in this way and how do I seperate them again?

Writing `y.1$Address` accesses all columns that begin with an "Address.XXX"

```
 > y.1
       Address.streetAddress Address.position.latitude Address.position.longitude Address.namedAreas Address.region.municipalityName Address.region.countyName Address.ocean nothing rent floor livingArea
    19    Västmannagatan 85C                  59.34500                   18.04370           Vasastan                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          2325 4100000 1586   1.0       40.0
    29          Redargatan 3                  59.30279                   18.09048   Hammarby Sjöstad                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1570 2800000 2829   4.0       43.5
    18 Doktor Abelins gata 6                  59.31596                   18.05454          Södermalm                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1223 4875000 3092    NA       70.0
    75     Sibeliusgången 34                  59.41581                   17.91272             Akalla                       Stockholm            Stockholms län            NA 1800000 4876   4.0       80.9
    16        Standarvägen 1                  59.27604                   18.00459       Gamla Älvsjö                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          6360 2950000 3983   1.0       91.0
    32    Kungsbro Strand 17                  59.33027                   18.05143        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1086 1995000 2017   1.0       25.5
    54        Pipersgatan 16                  59.33057                   18.04588        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1405 2195000 2105   3.0       27.0
    22   Alva Myrdals gata 4                  59.28650                   17.95199 Fruängen-Hägersten                       Stockholm            Stockholms län            NA 1995000 2587   3.0       37.0
    35   Norr Mälarstrand 24                  59.32687                   18.04522        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1437 2195000  910   4.0       23.0
    4    Beckbrännarbacken 7                  59.31487                   18.08901          Södermalm                       Stockholm            Stockholms län           329 1395000  520   0.5       11.0
> colnames(y.1)[1]  <- "nothing"
> y.1
   nothing.streetAddress nothing.position.latitude nothing.position.longitude nothing.namedAreas nothing.region.municipalityName nothing.region.countyName nothing.ocean listPrice rent floor livingArea
19    Västmannagatan 85C                  59.34500                   18.04370           Vasastan                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          2325   4100000 1586   1.0       40.0
29          Redargatan 3                  59.30279                   18.09048   Hammarby Sjöstad                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1570   2800000 2829   4.0       43.5
18 Doktor Abelins gata 6                  59.31596                   18.05454          Södermalm                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1223   4875000 3092    NA       70.0
75     Sibeliusgången 34                  59.41581                   17.91272             Akalla                       Stockholm            Stockholms län            NA   1800000 4876   4.0       80.9
16        Standarvägen 1                  59.27604                   18.00459       Gamla Älvsjö                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          6360   2950000 3983   1.0       91.0
32    Kungsbro Strand 17                  59.33027                   18.05143        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1086   1995000 2017   1.0       25.5
54        Pipersgatan 16                  59.33057                   18.04588        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1405   2195000 2105   3.0       27.0
22   Alva Myrdals gata 4                  59.28650                   17.95199 Fruängen-Hägersten                       Stockholm            Stockholms län            NA   1995000 2587   3.0       37.0
35   Norr Mälarstrand 24                  59.32687                   18.04522        Kungsholmen                       Stockholm            Stockholms län          1437   2195000  910   4.0       23.0
4    Beckbrännarbacken 7                  59.31487                   18.08901          Södermalm                       Stockholm            Stockholms län           329   1395000  520   0.5       11.0

> dput(y.1)
structure(list(Address = structure(list(address = structure(list(
    streetAddress = c("Västmannagatan 85C", "Redargatan 3", "Doktor Abelins gata 6", 
    "Sibeliusgången 34", "Standarvägen 1", "Kungsbro Strand 17", 
    "Pipersgatan 16", "Alva Myrdals gata 4", "Norr Mälarstrand 24", 
    "Beckbrännarbacken 7")), .Names = "streetAddress", row.names = c(19L, 
29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    position = structure(list(latitude = c(59.3449965, 59.3027897, 
    59.3159556, 59.4158109, 59.27603539, 59.33027358, 59.330567, 
    59.28649604, 59.326869, 59.314867), longitude = c(18.0437004, 
    18.0904824, 18.054536, 17.91271847, 18.00459327, 18.05143325, 
    18.045882, 17.95199275, 18.045217, 18.089009)), .Names = c("latitude", 
    "longitude"), row.names = c(19L, 29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 
    54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), namedAreas = list(
        "Vasastan", "Hammarby Sjöstad", "Södermalm", "Akalla", 
        "Gamla Älvsjö", "Kungsholmen", "Kungsholmen", "Fruängen-Hägersten", 
        "Kungsholmen", "Södermalm"), region = structure(list(
        municipalityName = c("Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", 
        "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", 
        "Stockholm", "Stockholm"), countyName = c("Stockholms län", 
        "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län", 
        "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län", 
        "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län", "Stockholms län")), .Names = c("municipalityName", 
    "countyName"), row.names = c(19L, 29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 
    54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), distance = structure(list(
        ocean = c(2325L, 1570L, 1223L, NA, 6360L, 1086L, 1405L, 
        NA, 1437L, 329L)), .Names = "ocean", row.names = c(19L, 
    29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("address", 
"position", "namedAreas", "region", "distance"), row.names = c(19L, 
29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    nothing = c(4100000L, 2800000L, 4875000L, 1800000L, 2950000L, 
    1995000L, 2195000L, 1995000L, 2195000L, 1395000L), rent = c(1586L, 
    2829L, 3092L, 4876L, 3983L, 2017L, 2105L, 2587L, 910L, 520L
    ), floor = c(1, 4, NA, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 0.5), livingArea = c(40, 
    43.5, 70, 80.9, 91, 25.5, 27, 37, 23, 11), source = structure(list(
        name = c("BOSTHLM", "Fastighetsbyrån", "Gripsholms Fastighetsförmedling", 
        "Fastighetsbyrån", "Fastighetsbyrån", "Mäklarhuset", 
        "SkandiaMäklarna", "Svenska Mäklarhuset", "Svensk Fastighetsförmedling", 
        "Svensk Fastighetsförmedling"), id = c(1499L, 1573L, 
        9895524L, 1573L, 1573L, 204L, 1570L, 58L, 713L, 713L), 
        type = c("Broker", "Broker", "Broker", "Broker", "Broker", 
        "Broker", "Broker", "Broker", "Broker", "Broker"), url = c("http://www.bosthlm.se/", 
        "http://www.fastighetsbyran.se/", "http://gripsholms.se/", 
        "http://www.fastighetsbyran.se/", "http://www.fastighetsbyran.se/", 
        "http://www.maklarhuset.se/", "http://www.skandiamaklarna.se/", 
        "http://www.svenskamaklarhuset.se/", "http://www.svenskfast.se/", 
        "http://www.svenskfast.se/")), .Names = c("name", "id", 
    "type", "url"), row.names = c(19L, 29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 
    54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), rooms = c(2, 1.5, 
    2.5, 3, 3.5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), published = structure(c(16632, 
    16631, 16631, 16629, 16626, 16626, 16626, 16626, 16626, 16626
    ), class = "Date"), constructionYear = c(NA, 2008L, 1929L, 
    1977L, 1937L, 1934L, 1934L, NA, 1907L, 1929L), objectType = c("Lägenhet", 
    "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", 
    "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet", "Lägenhet"), booliId = c(1919949L, 
    1893141L, 1896584L, 1898347L, 1917520L, 1918305L, 1918270L, 
    1918145L, 1918063L, 1918049L), soldDate = structure(c(16635, 
    16633, 16636, 16630, 16636, 16632, 16632, 16635, 16632, 16636
    ), class = "Date"), soldPrice = c(4100000L, 2950000L, 5175000L, 
    1800000L, 4200000L, 2510000L, 2610000L, 2500000L, 2950000L, 
    1850000L), url = c("https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/vasastan/vastmannagatan+85c/1919949", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/hammarby+sjostad/redargatan+3/1893141", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/sodermalm/doktor+abelins+gata+6/1896584", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/akalla/sibeliusgangen+34/1898347", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/gamla+alvsjo/standarvagen+1/1917520", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/kungsholmen/kungsbro+strand+17/1918305", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/kungsholmen/pipersgatan+16/1918270", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/fruangen-hagersten/alva+myrdals+gata+4/1918145", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/kungsholmen/norr+malarstrand+24/1918063", 
    "https://www.booli.se/bostad/lagenhet/sodermalm/beckbrannarbacken+7/1918049"
    ), isNewConstruction = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), plotArea = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA), additionalArea = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), AreaSize = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10", "20", 
    "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "110", "120", 
    "130"), class = "factor"), PriceDiff = c(0L, 150000L, 300000L, 
    0L, 1250000L, 515000L, 415000L, 505000L, 755000L, 455000L
    )), .Names = c("Address", "nothing", "rent", "floor", "livingArea", 
"source", "rooms", "published", "constructionYear", "objectType", 
"booliId", "soldDate", "soldPrice", "url", "isNewConstruction", 
"plotArea", "additionalArea", "AreaSize", "PriceDiff"), row.names = c(19L, 
29L, 18L, 75L, 16L, 32L, 54L, 22L, 35L, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So it was not a data.frame, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533936/knitr-error-in-usemethodround-any-no-applicable-method-for-round-any-appl

Comment: Update your post with `dput(y)`, so we can reproduce exactly the same dataset.

Comment: Well. Writing class(y.1) generates a data.frame response. I have updated the post with the dput(y) output as you requested.

Comment: `str(y.1)` shows that some of the objects of you data.frame are themselves data.frames

Comment: Yes. What I would like to know is the setup. From what I've read, having data.frames within a data.frame is not possible? Or is the y.1 data.frame really a list? And how is the columns grouped in such a way that one can reference several of them through their hierarchical upper data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that data structure came from parsing JSON.  You can `flatten` it to a regular `data.frame` with the function from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
flat <- flatten(y.1)
str(flat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  28 variables:
#  $ nothing                        : int  4100000 2800000 4875000 1800000 2950000 1995000 2195000 1995000 2195000 1395000
#  $ rent                           : int  1586 2829 3092 4876 3983 2017 2105 2587 910 520
#  $ floor                          : num  1 4 NA 4 1 1 3 3 4 0.5
# ...
```

So, the nested `data.frames` have been expanded out into their own columns.  To go back the other way seems harder, it doesn't look like the package supplies that functionality.  You can get a similar structure with a recursive function that generates a nested list, where base elements may be `data.frames`.  `data.frames` are basically lists anyway, so this structure isn't too far off.  Here are two functions, one that generates nested `data.frames`, the other that give nested lists (more standard structure I think).

```
## A function to create the nested data.frames structure
collapse <- function(dat) {
    prefixes <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+)\\..*", "\\1", names(dat))
    ns <- table(prefixes)
    out <- dat[, !(prefixes %in% names(ns)[ns>1])]
    for (n in names(ns)[ns>1]) {
        inds <- grepl(n, names(dat))
        subDat <- setNames(dat[, inds], gsub(sprintf("^%s\\.", n), "", names(dat[, inds])))
        res <- collapse(subDat)
        out[[n]] <- res
    }
    return( out )
}

out <- collapse(flat)
str(out)

# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  19 variables:
#  $ nothing          : int  4100000 2800000 4875000 1800000 2950000 1995000 2195000 1995000 2195000 1395000
#  $ rent             : int  1586 2829 3092 4876 3983 2017 2105 2587 910 520
#  $ floor            : num  1 4 NA 4 1 1 3 3 4 0.5
# ...
#  $ source           :'data.frame':    10 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ name: chr  "BOSTHLM" "Fastighetsbyrån" "Gripsholms Fastighetsförmedling" "Fastighetsbyrån" ...
#   ..$ id  : int  1499 1573 9895524 1573 1573 204 1570 58 713 713
#   ..$ type: chr  "Broker" "Broker" "Broker" "Broker" ...
# ...

## Function to produce nested lists that may contain data.frames as
## base elements
collapseNestedLists <- function(dat) {
    prefixes <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+)\\..*", "\\1", names(dat))
    ns <- table(prefixes)
    out <- as.list(dat[, !(prefixes %in% names(ns)[ns>1])])
    for (n in names(ns)[ns>1]) {
        inds <- grepl(n, names(dat))
        subDat <- setNames(dat[, inds], gsub(sprintf("^%s\\.", n), "", names(dat[, inds])))
        res <- collapse(subDat)
        out[[n]] <- as.list(res)
    }
    return( out )
}

outList <- collapseNestedLists(flat)
```

Both of these data structures are accessible in basically the same way.  If you wanted to pull out the position of an address (so an element in a `data.frame` nested within a `data.frame` in your original structure) or these,

```
all.equal(
    outList$Address$position$latitude[1],
    out$Address$position$latitude[1],
    y.1$Address$position$latitude[1],
    y.1[["Address"]][["position"]][["latitude"]][1]
)
# TRUE
```